# Jooq specified packages are not generated. Incorrect syntax?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

While trying to generate the Oracle database packages using jooq, the packages specified are not extracted when the list of packages is specified. However when specifying a single package, everything works fine. Also, generation works well when generating everything.
(.*). But in my app all objects are not required.

Could you please advise what's wrong with my config?

(the whole config is omitted for simplicity)

**package generated fine:**

```xml
...
<database>
    <name>org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase</name>
    <inputSchema>MY_SCHEMA</inputSchema>
    <includes>PKG_ABC</includes>
...
```

**packages are not generated:**

```xml
...
<database>
    <name>org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase</name>
    <inputSchema>MY_SCHEMA</inputSchema>
    <includes>PKG_ABC,PKG_CDE,PKG_FGH</includes>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<includes>` and `<excludes>` configuration elements expect a *single regular expression* to match objects. I.e., use pipes `|` instead of commas `,`:

```xml
<includes>PKG_ABC|PKG_CDE|PKG_FGH</includes>
```

In fact, the manual is misleading and contains wrong information, which will be fixed with [#2720](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2720)... Support for comma-separated lists of regular expressions was [removed with jOOQ 3.0](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/reference/migrating-to-3.0/#N13700)